# integrating f(x)=1/x from -a to a. convergent or divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

we are discussing improper integrals in Calc II, and I am failing to understand why the integral from $-a$ to $a$ of $f(x)=1/x$ is not zero.

Since the function is odd and thus symmetric about the origin and the line $y=x$ (also $y=-x$), it looks like the area from $-a$ to $0$ is just the negative of the area from $0$ to $a$. Anything plus its opposite is zero. I get that it can get weird when dealing with infinity (the areas are infinite in size), but they seem to be the "same" infinity.

I understand how to find out that the integral diverges, but am wondering why that is so.

I am also interested in understanding why the integral from negative infinity to infinity of $f(x)=1/x$ isn't $0$, but I figure that I should understand the first question more thoroughly before adding more infinities into the mix!

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: There is a discontinuity from negative infinity to infinity and thus the integral must be split up into two separate integrals. The function is discontinuous at $0$, you cannot leave this important matter...

Comment: To make matters even "worse", when you integrate the function $y=\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ from negative infinity to positive infinity, even that integral is divergent, though there is no discontinuity anywhere. Yet, the integral must be split into two separate integrals (split at $0$ or anywhere else for that matter). The two separate integrals diverge! Only if the values of $x$ are finite, say integrating from $-1million$ to $1 million$, the integral is zero

Answer (score 1):

The improper integral $\int_{-a}^a\frac{dx}{x}$ is by definition equal to
$$ \lim_{r_1\to 0^{+}}\int_{r_1}^a\frac{dx}{x}+\lim_{r_2\to 0^{-}}\int_{-a}^{r_2}\frac{dx}{x}$$
and since both integrals diverge, the integral is undefined.

On the other hand, the Cauchy principal value is:
$$ \lim_{r\to 0^+}\Big[\int_{r}^a\frac{dx}{x}+\int_{-a}^{-r}\frac{dx}{x}\Big]=0 $$
since the integrals cancel as you have observed.